# Creating a foreign key on an exisiting column in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, activerecord

I am trying to create two tables in Ruby on Rails which are both to be populated by seeding CSV files. Both files already contain an ID column `fsa_id` that I would like to use as the primary/foreign keys for my tables.

So far I have the following table migrations:

names:

```
  class CreateNames < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :names do |t|
      t.integer :fsa_id
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Locations:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.integer :fsa_id
      t.string :adress
      t.string :postcode
      t.integer :lattitude
      t.integer :longitude
      t.string :local_authority

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What I am looking to do is make `fsa_id` the primary key on the names table and the foreign key on the locations table.

As I understand I can do this by adding the following to the locations migration file:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.integer :fsa_id
      t.string :adress
      t.string :postcode
      t.integer :lattitude
      t.integer :longitude
      t.string :local_authority

      t.timestamps
    end
    # Adds a foreign key constraint to the fsa_id column
    # Links to the names table which uses the same named column.
    add_foreign_key :locations, 
                :names, 
                column: :fsa_id,
                primary_key: :fsa_id
  end
end
```

However, when I add this and try to run `rails db:migrate` I get the following error:

```
== 20201116221428 CreateLocations: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:locations)
   -> 0.0017s
-- add_foreign_key(:locations, :names, {:column=>:fsa_id, :primary_key=>:fsa_id})
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

SQLite3::SQLException: foreign key mismatch - "locations" referencing "names"
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/db/migrate/20201116221428_create_locations.rb:15:in `change'
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: foreign key mismatch - "locations" referencing "names"
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/db/migrate/20201116221428_create_locations.rb:15:in `change'
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'

Caused by:
SQLite3::SQLException: foreign key mismatch - "locations" referencing "names"
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/db/migrate/20201116221428_create_locations.rb:15:in `change'
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
/home/jonathon/Projects/waad/jpd_individual_2020/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have tried looking around but most answers seem to assume either the `id` of the table is to be used or that the table will grow itself.

For full reference the CSV files to seed the database are laid out like this:

names.csv:

[image]

locations.csv:

[image]

If anyone could help with this issue I would be very grateful.

EDIT:

I am using Postgress in production:

my Gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.3', '>= 6.0.3.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3', '~> 1.4', '>= 1.4.2', group: :production
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 4.1'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'chartkick'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.2', require: false

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
 end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On `CreateNames` migration you may use `primary_key: :fsa_id` option.

```
class CreateNames < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :names, primary_key: :fsa_id do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

`CreateLocations` migration remain as you have posted.

Also you need setup associations in models like:

```
class Name < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :location, primary_key: :fsa_id
end
```

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :name, foreign_key: :fsa_id, primary_key: :fsa_id
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to modify or add a foreign key to your existing table, you should create a new migration to avoid to break your code in production.